# Why use ps -ef check the process every time the pid will change?

Tags: terminal, command-line, macos

I use the `ps -ef` to check the process, but every time the pid will change, you see the below, `1726`-> `1728`->...

```
aircraftdeMacBook-Pro:etc ldl$ ps -ef | grep safira
  501  1726   527   0 10:14上午 ttys000    0:00.00 grep safira
aircraftdeMacBook-Pro:etc ldl$ ps -ef | grep safira
  501  1728   527   0 10:14上午 ttys000    0:00.00 grep safira
aircraftdeMacBook-Pro:etc ldl$ ps -ef | grep safira
  501  2298   527   0 11:18上午 ttys000    0:00.00 grep safira
aircraftdeMacBook-Pro:etc ldl$ ps -ef | grep safira
  501  2301   527   0 11:18上午 ttys000    0:00.00 grep safira
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you run this in Terminal two new processes for `ps` and `grep` are created, run to do their job and then terminated successfully. So each invocation gets new PIDs.

---

To properly exclude the process *grep search_string* from grep'ing for *search_string* in the ps result use:

```
ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep search_string
```

or

```
ps -ef | grep [s]earch_string
```

e.g. `ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep safira` or `ps -ef | grep [s]afira`

Answer (score 0):

The `ps ... | grep ...` pipeline can often be replaced with `pgrep` (or `pkill`) which unlike the pipeline are clever enough not to match themselves:

```
pgrep safira
```

Comment: I use the `pgrep safira`, gets nothing.

Comment: @aircraft and neither did `ps ... | grep ...` which only managed to incorrectly match itself.